# Resharper rename - prevent from searching references in all files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I'm using Typescript and Visual Studio 2015 with Resharper 9. Lets say I want to rename my angular controller method from activate to init. What happens is that Resharper start searching through all suspicious references in libs like angular.js, jquery.js and so on. It also scans all razor views to find possible usages. This operation some times is really slow and is not logical because I will never want to rename something in angular.js library. How can I skip such files from scanning at all?

[image: Resharper rename]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Resharper 2016.3 JetBrains have introduced [Third Party Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Reference_Options_Code_Editing_Third_Party_Code.html). This allows to completely ignore folders or pattern-matched files for JS libraries.

[image: Third Party Code in R#]

I've tried and this indeed ignores excluded files for scan on renames.

However I'm not entirely sure why they have added yet another location where to specify ignored files. They already had **Elements to Skip** in **Code Inspection => Settings** and in **Environment => Search & Navigation**

**UPDATE** through this screen you can't exclude files/folders that are not part of the VS solution. There is a [bugreport](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-462950) to that effect. Please vote and comment there.

Comment: Works for me! With the release of ReSharper 2016.3 this should be the accepted solution.

Comment: It seems, it works only files, directories are part of the solution. If you want to add folder or file which is there but not part of the solution (e.g. `node_modules/@angular` directory). Next time ReSharper will scan these files and folders too.

Comment: @SayusiAndo yes, indeed, I've observed this problem as well. Have you reported this issue to JetBrains?

Comment: Not yet, I'll do it by EOB.

Comment: @SayusiAndo Good stuff!

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Refactorings__Rename.html
it is not possible to exclude specific files or filemasks. It has been asked for, though.

**Update:**
With the release of ReSharper 2016.3 it is now possible to exclude folders, specific files and filemasks. Please see trailmax's answer.